# Plotting solution to an oscillation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, functions, variable-definitions

I have a simple task of plotting the solution to a differential equation under different conditions and can't figure it out.

The solution is

```
x(t)=Exp(-bt)[cos(wt)+(b/w)*sin(wt)]
```

and I need to plot it for 0

```
f[t_, b_] := [(e^(-b*t))[Cos[t] + b*Sin[t]], 
 t, {t, 0, 20}]
```

and I think something is wrong in my syntax. I will appreciate any guidance!

Comment: You have to use brackets instead of parentheses for arguments. Moreover, you might want `Sin` and `Cos` instead of `sin` and `cos`. Mathematica is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
x[t_, b_, w_] := Exp[-b t] (Cos[w t] + b t Sinc[w t])
Manipulate[
 Plot[x[t, b, w], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}],
 {{b, .1}, -2, 2},
 {{w, 1.}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

If you have specific values for `b` to plot, you can use, e.g.,

```
Plot[{f[t,0],f[t,0.1],f[t,1.]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

Comment: So I did this, `f[t_, b_] := Exp[b t] (Cos[t] + b*Sin[t])` which worked great for my function, but them plotting I don't get anything on the plot. I don't want to use the manipulate function because I want to pick specific values for b.

Comment: How did you plot then? Note that `b` needs a specific value if want to use `Plot[f[t,b],{t,0,20}]`.

Comment: `Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 20}]`

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to include b; I need it at specific values of 0, 0.1, and 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want plots for b from 0 to 1, you can do this

```
f[t_, b_] := Exp[-b t] (Cos[t] + b*Sin[t])

Table[Plot[f[t, b], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLabel -> "b=" + b], {b, 0, 1, .1}]
```

but as above, Manipulate works too if you just want to vary b.

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[t, b], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> "b=" + b], {b, 0, 1, .1}]
```